# How to push commit changes to aws remote server instance?

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, gitlab

I have follow these instructions https://alphacoder.xyz/git-push-to-an-aws-ec2-remote-using-a-pem-file/ .But it doesn't work.

Comment: What does not work?

Comment: warning: setting remote service path not supported by protocol
remote: The project you were looking for could not be found or you don't have permission to view it.
fatal: repository 'https://gitlab.com/example.git/' not found

Comment: I got this everytime when I try to push origin.

Comment: The instructions are for pushing to an aws ec2 machine, not to push to GitLab. I don't see "GitLab" in your referenced link (https://alphacoder.xyz/git-push-to-an-aws-ec2-remote-using-a-pem-file/).

Comment: In face, I have a project on aws instance remote server with ssh. I used this instance ssh to download that project to my local. And I made some changes to that project and pushes my commit changes but it throws me ```warning: setting remote service path not supported by protocol remote: The project you were looking for could not be found or you don't have permission to view it. fatal: repository``` even I downloaded. Sorry for my english. Thank you Sir.

Comment: OK. I have edited the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238788/discussion-between-zin-minhtun-and-vonc).

Answer (score 0):

The latest official instructions are "[Connect to your Linux instance using an SSH client](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AccessingInstancesLinux.html)", on Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud.
This might be more reliable than a post from 2017.

Don't forget to answer yes at the first connection (`ssh -i /path/my-key-pair.pem my-instance-user-name@my-instance-public-dns-name`):

```
The authenticity of host 'ec2-198-51-100-1.compute-1.amazonaws.com (198-51-100-1)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is l4UB/neBad9tvkgJf1QZWxheQmR59WgrgzEimCG6kZY.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?

(yes)

Warning: Permanently added 'ec2-198-51-100-1.compute-1.amazonaws.com' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
```

Once connected, you would need to generate a different set of SSH key, in order to register the public one to your GitLab account, and clone the GitLab repository on that instance.
See "[GitLab and SSH keys](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ssh/)".

---

> I have a project on aws instance remote server with ssh. I used this instance ssh to download that project to my local

If you are copying (scp) the remote AWS project locally, you would end up with the AWS .git repo, and its setting, hence the remote GitLab.

You would need locally to generate a new ssh key, register it to your GitLab account, and use it before being able to push back to GitLab.

Comment: Yes, connection between remote and local fully established. When I try ```git remote -v``` it also says ```origin  https://gitlab.com/vinova/uplyrn/uplyrn-redesign.git (fetch)    
origin  https://gitlab.com/vinova/uplyrn/uplyrn-redesign.git (push)```. But I cant push to that remote. Is there any missing that I forgot. Thank you.

Comment: @zin-minhtun I have edited the answer to address that.

Comment: It means my local ssh key would be needed to add to my gitlab repository?

Comment: @zin-minhtun A different set would be needed. As a best practice, you do not reuse the existing keys to access new resources.

Comment: By the way, does it work by adding remote ssh key to my local machine and push to remote repo? Because I haven't access to that project repository but I have remote server ssh key. Thanks

Comment: @zin-minhtun There is no such thing as "remote SSH keys": ssh keys are always local. Especially the private SSH key which, as its name suggests, is private. Meaning it is not reused elsewhere. It should remain a *local* key.

Comment: Sorry for my misunderstanding. I means server ssh key. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238789/discussion-between-vonc-and-zin-minhtun).